# Downcasting on protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have the following code:

```
protocol Step { /* body */ }

enum StepA: Int, CaseIterable, Step {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

enum StepB: Int, CaseIterable, Step {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

protocol Component {
    var step: Step { get }
}

protocol ComponentA: Component {
    var step: StepA { get }
}

protocol ComponentB: Component {
    var step: StepB { get }
}


struct SomeComponentOfTypeA: ComponentA {
    var step: StepA = StepA.one
}


let a = SomeComponentOfTypeA()

print(a.step)
```

The type of **a.step** I would like to be **StepA**, since I am initalizing this way.
But, I can't do that because:

```
struct SomeComponentOfTypeA: ComponentA {
    var step: StepA = StepA.one
}
```

the compiler tells me that:

> Type 'SomeComponentOfTypeA' does not conform to protocol 'Component'

Basically, it doesn't know that since I am implementing the **ComponentA**, my step should be of type **StepA** too.

As a workaround I found that if I modify this part:

```
protocol Component {
    var step: Step { get }
}
```

into:

```
protocol Component {
    associatedtype SomeStep: Step
    var step: SomeStep { get }
}
```

Everything works just fine, **a.step** is of **StepA**, no issues at all...

Question: why is this working? I am basically hiding the fact that **step** property from **Component** is of type **Step**, by using the associated type **SomeStep**.
This is kinda weird, isn't it? I was expecting this to work just fine without having to hide anything, why is this happening? How does it work?

Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Using associated type looks like the right solution here because trying to hide a property by shadowing it with one with the same name looks like a bad design

Comment: Sorry but I am not following, it's the right solution but also by having the same name makes it look like a bad design?

Comment: I was some what unclear sorry. I meant that the original implementation, shadowing the property, was a bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol can be adopted by a struct or enum so it don't do class polymorphism, because they can not be inherited. This is also one of the reasons that why `associatedtype` exists.

Back to your question, you defined a variable with the same name as the parent protocol in the sub-protocol, but the type is different, this is allowed because the protocol is not a concrete type. But this is not a type overload, because the protocol works differently from the class.

In this case, you'd better use generics, which is `associatedtype`. But if you have to use these three protocols, you only need to declare the sub-protocol.

```
...

protocol ComponentA: Component {}

protocol ComponentB: Component {}

struct SomeComponentOfTypeA: ComponentA {
  var step: Step = StepA.one
}

struct SomeComponentOfTypeB: ComponentB {
  var step: Step = StepB.two
}

let a = SomeComponentOfTypeA()

print(a.step)
print(type(of: a))

let b = SomeComponentOfTypeB()

print(b.step)
print(type(of: b))
```

Output:

```
one
SomeComponentOfTypeA
two
SomeComponentOfTypeB
```

Another way is to meet your needs. Limit `SomeComponentOfTypeA` only allows `StepA` type.

```
protocol StepAProtocol { /* body */ }
protocol StepBProtocol { /* body */ }

enum StepA: Int, CaseIterable, StepAProtocol {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

enum StepB: Int, CaseIterable, StepBProtocol {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

protocol Component {
  associatedtype T
  var step: T { get }
}

protocol ComponentA: Component where T: StepAProtocol  {}
protocol ComponentB: Component where T: StepBProtocol  {}

struct SomeComponentOfTypeA: ComponentA {
  var step: StepA = .one
}

struct SomeComponentOfTypeB: ComponentB {
  var step: StepB = .two
}

struct SomeComponentOfTypeC: ComponentB {
  var step: StepA = .two // error: Type 'StepA' does not conform to protocol 'StepBProtocol'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, also I should specify that I wanted to make it in such way that whoever conforms to protocol ComponentA or ComponentB will be forced to have a step property of type StepA, respectively StepB. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need all the protocols? You could do this with associated values:

```
protocol Step { /* body */ }

enum StepA: Int, CaseIterable, Step {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

enum StepB: Int, CaseIterable, Step {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

enum Component {
    case typeA(StepA)
    case typeB(StepB)
}

let component = Component.typeA(StepA.one)
```

Comment: Yes, I need all the protocols, you can consider it an experiment. I am trying to understand if what I did as an workaround is bad, why it works, if protocol extensions do class polymorphism, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the way the protocols are defined.

1. Protocol Component has a variable `step` of type `Step`(a protocol)
2. The variable `step` gets redeclared in protocol ComponentA
3. So when defining `SomeComponentOfTypeA` the compiler gives an error as it finds `step` of type `StepA` per `ComponentA` but not of type `Step` per `Component` protocol.
4. When you define AssociatedType, you then make use of generics to specify that `step` variable in `Component` can be of any type following protocol `Step`
5. So now ComponentA's step variable satisfies point 4 and hence no error.

And therefore, what you did finally using generics is the right approach for such a case, if you really wanted to redeclare the variable `step` in `ComponentA` for a specific type `StepA`.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer, but how come that the compiler lets me redeclare the variable step in protocol ComponentA and ComponentB? It does let me, the problem appears only when some struct/class tries to implement ComponentA/ComponentB, then it can't figure it out..

Comment: True, because the case for a protocol is technically still valid. Only when a protocol is followed through a struct/class will one be implementing it right? 
That's why the error then:)